# Deploy xmarian app on samsung Tablet

Tags: android, deployment, xamarin.android

I have developed a simple app for my personal use which i don't intend to put on store. what are my options to get it on a Galaxy Tablet once and use it again and again on same tablet without connecting to laptop

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

once you debug and deploy your app to your phone, it get installed and you can use it anytime.
[image]

Method 2 :

change mode from debug to release and then deploy your app.You will get an apk file in your project folder.Install that apk on any device on which you want to run your application.
[image]

[image]